# Android SLF4J: NoClassDefFoundError android.util.Log

Tags: android, osgi, slf4j, ipojo

I am porting an existing OSGi/Felix/iPOJO app from a windows over to Android. The app is using  SLF4J.  I have slf4j-android deployed as a bundle.  However I am getting a **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.Log** on the line where I am trying to instantiate the logger.

The SLF4J documentation says that I only need to have the slf4j-android jar on my classpath, no further configuration is necessary. (http://www.slf4j.org/android/)

My logger is declared as:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DefaultActionManager");
```

The line the stack trace is complaining about is:

```
logger.info("Bound new action list for state " + state);
```

Here is the full method:

```
@Override
@Bind(aggregate = true)
public void bindActionList(final ActionList actionList) {
    final State state = actionList.getState();

    final ActionList replacedActionList = actionLists.put(state, actionList);
    logger.info("Bound new action list for state " + state);

    if (replacedActionList != null) {
        logger.warn(state + " previously had an action list associated with it. This new action list replaced it.");
    }
}
```

Any clues why I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError on android.util.Log when I reference the logger?

Full stack trace:

```
{ERROR]  : The method bindActionList in the implementation class myCompany.DefaultActio
nManager throws an exception : android.util.Log
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.Log
 at org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLogger.info(AndroidLogger.java:151)
 at myCompany.DefaultActionManager.__bindActionList(DefaultActionManager.java:120)
 at myCompany.DefaultActionManager.bindActionList(DefaultActionManager.java)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Callback.call(Callback.java:260)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyCallback.callOnInstance(DependencyCa
llback.java:309)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.Dependency.invokeCallback(Dependency.java:315)

 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.Dependency.onObjectCreation(Dependency.java:28
0)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.__M_onCreation(DependencyHan
dler.java:643)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.onCreation(DependencyHandler
.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.getPojoObject(InstanceManager.java:870)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Callback.call(Callback.java:233)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Callback.call(Callback.java:193)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.lifecycle.callback.LifecycleCallback.call(LifecycleCallba
ck.java:86)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.lifecycle.callback.LifecycleCallbackHandler.__M_stateChan
ged(LifecycleCallbackHandler.java:162)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.lifecycle.callback.LifecycleCallbackHandler.stateChanged(
LifecycleCallbackHandler.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.setState(InstanceManager.java:472)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.stateChanged(InstanceManager.java:1340)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.setState(InstanceManager.java:497)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.HandlerManager.stateChanged(HandlerManager.java:239)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Handler.setValidity(Handler.java:174)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.__M_checkContext(DependencyH
andler.java:186)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.checkContext(DependencyHandl
er.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.__M_validate(DependencyHandl
er.java:149)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.validate(DependencyHandler.j
ava)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.validate(DependencyModel.java:642)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.computeDependencyState(DependencyModel.java:3
10)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.manageArrival(DependencyModel.java:399)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.addedService(DependencyModel.java:335)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.trackAdding(Tracker.java:725)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.track(Tracker.java:686)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(Tracker.java:647)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispat
cher.java:932)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java
:793)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543
)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.IPojoContext.registerService(IPojoContext.java:385)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedService.registerService(ProvidedS
ervice.java:362)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedServiceHandler.__M_stateChanged(P
rovidedServiceHandler.java:509)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedServiceHandler.stateChanged(Provi
dedServiceHandler.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.setState(InstanceManager.java:472)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.stateChanged(InstanceManager.java:1340)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.setState(InstanceManager.java:497)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.HandlerManager.stateChanged(HandlerManager.java:239)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Handler.setValidity(Handler.java:174)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.__M_checkContext(DependencyH
andler.java:186)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.checkContext(DependencyHandl
er.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.__M_validate(DependencyHandl
er.java:149)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.dependency.DependencyHandler.validate(DependencyHandler.j
ava)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.validate(DependencyModel.java:642)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.computeDependencyState(DependencyModel.java:3
10)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.manageArrival(DependencyModel.java:399)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.DependencyModel.addedService(DependencyModel.java:335)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.trackAdding(Tracker.java:725)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.track(Tracker.java:686)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Tracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(Tracker.java:647)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispat
cher.java:932)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java
:793)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543
)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.IPojoContext.registerService(IPojoContext.java:385)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedService.registerService(ProvidedS
ervice.java:362)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedServiceHandler.__M_stateChanged(P
rovidedServiceHandler.java:509)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.providedservice.ProvidedServiceHandler.stateChanged(Provi
dedServiceHandler.java)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.setState(InstanceManager.java:472)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceManager.start(InstanceManager.java:354)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.ComponentFactory.createInstance(ComponentFactory.java:178)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.IPojoFactory.createComponentInstance(IPojoFactory.java:301)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.IPojoFactory.createComponentInstance(IPojoFactory.java:238)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceCreator$ManagedInstance.create(InstanceCreator.java:343)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.InstanceCreator.addInstance(InstanceCreator.java:89)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Extender.parse(Extender.java:306)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Extender.startManagementFor(Extender.java:237)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Extender.access$600(Extender.java:52)
 at org.apache.felix.ipojo.Extender$CreatorThread.run(Extender.java:769)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your framework is exporting the android.util package. If not, configure Felix do so so (by adding an extra package).

Also check that the android slf4j bundle is importing the android.util package.

Clement

Comment: Clement, thanks for the feedback.
I have verified android.util is exported in my feilx config.properties under my dalvik-1.6 section.
Also the slf4j bundle is importing the android.util package.